# MKPolyline Intersecting coordinates ios

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, mkpolyline, mkmapitem

**Please check this image first**

[image]

I have an array of lat long coordinates through which I created a `MKPolyline` now I want to find the intersecting point coordinates lat long of two `MKPolyline`.
For this I have tried MKPolyLine Intersects or not method but it only returns the bool value, not lat long coordinates. Also I have tried http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html to find out the mid point between 2 points but it's not working.
So can we find the exact intersecting point between two `MKPolyline`.

Comment: What you are using right now? Can you explain in details?

Comment: I am working on racing application in which user is logging all the GPS point with external GPS device and when he connect to that GPS device with my application then on mapview user is able to see all the travelled path now user can cut the travelled path from any where to mark the start line (Race Track) and based on start line i have to figure out how many laps user had travelled and other things.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/H2znR.png
In this image Blue line is user travelled path and white line is user Marked line
So I need the Intersecting point coordinates between both the PolyLine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
CGFloat m1, c1, m2, c2;
CGFloat x11, y11, x12, y12; //line 1
CGFloat x21, y21, x22, y22; //line 2
CGFloat dx, dy;
CGFloat intersection_X, intersection_Y;


dx = x12 - x11;
dy = y12 - y11;

m1 = dy / dx;
c1 = y11 - m1 * x11; 



dx = x22 - x21;
dy = y22 - y21;

m2 = dy / dx;
c2 = y22 - m2 * x22; 


if( (m1 - m2) == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"No Intersection between the lines");
}
else
{
    intersection_X = (c2 - c1) / (m1 - m2);
    intersection_Y = m1 * intersection_X + c1;
}
```

Comment: Accepted my friend, Once Again Many thanks for the help :-)

Comment: @rohitSidpara good bro...how to achieve the same in python ? Thanks in advance...love you dude